# Script Shell: grep specific lines - extract specific strings - put them on a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

From the  appache2 accesslog.log file I am trying to grep the lines where there is this string :  `"GET /kiosk/kioskconf.txt HTTP/1.1"`

For this I am using the command :

```
grep "GET /kiosk/kioskconf.txt HTTP/1.1"
```

Which works fine. e.g:

```
19x.25x.22x.5x - - [27/Apr/2015:14:15:50 +0200] "GET /kiosk/kioskconf.txt HTTP/1.1"
```

There is multiple lines like that and i wana extract to a file just the IP in the begining of each line. also i don't want to have same Ip's in the file.
i use this to extract the ip's but it's not complete.

```
sed -n 's/.*194\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
```

which displays:

```
.25x.22x.5x
```

but i wont the whole ip's and just one instance for each different ip's and put them on a file.

Can someone help me to sort this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you should be using awk:

```
awk '/GET \/kiosk\/kioskconf\.txt HTTP\/1\.1/ && !seen[$1]++ { print $1 }' file
```

This prints the first field `$1` whenever the pattern is matched but the IP address is not already in the array `seen`. It also increments the value of `seen[$1]` so next time the same IP occurs, the second part of the condition will be false and the line will not be printed.

`/` and `.` have special meaning in the regular expression pattern, so they must be escaped.

Comment: This is indeed the right way of getting this job done +1

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks for the explications and the command, it worked very well.
I am just wondering if you can just explain to me a little bit more about this part of the command : "&& !seen[$1]++".
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sort | uniq` commands to get unique values.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
grep "GET /kiosk/kioskconf.txt HTTP/1.1" | cut -f1 | sort -u
```

This will just strip all but the first, space seperated field in your `grep` output (i.e. the IP addresses) and then sort them, removing duplicates.